# Using recursive function to get data from parent nodes

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion, javascript-objects

I have a data structure like the following:

```
obj
 name
 parent
   name
   parent
     name
     parent
```

I'm trying to do a recursive function to get the name element for as long as there is a parent element. I've come up with the following code, but it doesn't work because it converts the result to a string (and not an object). Can someone give me some advice on how to best achieve this. The nesting of parent elements is varied, not fixed (even though above I only specified 3 layers). It can range from 1 to 100.

**My Desired Result**

My end goal is to extract all the 'name' elements from every 'parent' down the hierarchy (and push them to an array).

```
function getElem(obj){
    var result = '';
    var parent = '.parent';
    var temp = '';

    if(!obj.parent){
        return obj.name
    }
    else {
        //structure is obj.parent.parent.parent...name
        temp += parent;
        result = obj + temp + '.name';
        console.log(result);
        getElem(result);
    }
}
getElem(e.data);
```

Comment: Well so looking at this, I believe that if you want to return the parent object, you will have to return the object with all of it's children. But obviously it is returning a string, since you are returning `obj.name` which is a string

Answer (score 1):

```
function getElem(obj, arr) {
  arr = arr || [];
  if (obj.name) {
      arr.push(obj.name);
  }

  if (obj.parent) {
      return (getElem(obj.parent, arr));
  }
  else {
      return (arr);
  }
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v1Lhfam3/)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your data structure looks like this

```
    var obj = {
        name: 'abc',
        parent: {
            name: 'def',
            parent: {
                name: 'ghi',
                parent: {
                    name: 'jkl'
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

function for loop that walks recursively for "parent" key by assigning "parent" key's value in obj and breaks the loop when the key "parent" is not available...

```
    function get_names(obj, key) {
        var names = [];
        if(key == "undefined") {
            key = "parent"; // default value of key
        }
        do {

            if(typeof obj === "undefined") {
                break; // breaks the loop when obj/parent is undefined
            }
            names.push(obj.name); // pushes all the elements named as 'name'

        } while(obj = obj.parent);

        return names;
    }
```

Logs the array in console

```
    console.log(get_names(obj));
```

Comment: It would be better if you can explain why this code solves the problem.

Comment: @JorgeHortelano it is just a loop walking recursively on an object with comments attached.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. If somebody needs to search for the answer that suits better, must read and understand completely your code.

Comment: @JorgeHortelano I edited the post again please check and tell if it is okay. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need recursion.

```
function getElem(obj) {
    var names = [obj.name];
    while (obj.parent) {
        obj = obj.parent;
        names.push(obj.name);
    }
    return names;
}
```

Comment: This is ok but if the end goal is to extract all the names, you should declare an empty array at the beginning and push the node name on each iteration.

Comment: @pQuestions123: not quite. What I want is simply extract all the name elements from every parent down the hierarchy

Comment: @user1142130 modified to return array